# Ask Ubuntu App for Android

Tags: discussion, android

I've had a look and not been able to find anything but I thought I would ask just to make sure.

Is there a Ask Ubuntu app for android or do I just have to use the browser?

Comment: Thanks, I have installed StackAnywhere Gold. Still kind of new and just realized this should be a Meta question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, there is no official Ask Ubuntu app for Android. However, a Stack Exchange app should work for Ask Ubuntu, as it is a Stack Exchange site. Try the Stack Remote app.